# How I can stop an application from my application

Tags: android, root, kill

I'm programming a launcher, and I want to kill external app when the launcher resume. My device is root and I put permissions in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
```

I try to kill with this code, but doesn't works.

```
public void killApp(String appPackage) {

    ActivityManager manager =  (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> activityes = ((ActivityManager)manager).getRunningAppProcesses();

    for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < activityes.size(); iCnt++){
        if (activityes.get(iCnt).processName.contains(appPackage)){
            manager.killBackgroundProcesses(appPackage);
            android.os.Process.sendSignal(activityes.get(iCnt).pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
            android.os.Process.killProcess(activityes.get(iCnt).pid);
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong? Is there any alternative to kill an application?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With root you could do this:

```
public void killApp(String appPackage) {

        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> activityes = ((ActivityManager) manager).getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < activityes.size(); iCnt++) {
            if (activityes.get(iCnt).processName.contains(appPackage)) {

                try {
                    Process rootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su"});

                    String command = "kill - 9 " + activityes.get(iCnt).pid;

                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(rootProcess.getOutputStream()), 2048);
                    try {
                        bw.write(command);
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```